# Use case diagram for book exchanging system

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

[image: Use case diagram for book exchanging system]

Is the diagram correct? Can more use cases be added in this diagram? Is there a need for include and extend functionalities?

Comment: What are the criteria for "_correct_"? What is the assignment specification? If it was "try draw few bubbles around story: a student walks into the public library" then it's correct, you could make it even smaller. BTW: see also [Wikipedia: Use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) which describes what kind of text description is typically hidden behind such bubbles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagrams look ok and you can add more use cases at your wish. But for clarity sake it's advisable to split them into sub-domains where you can focus on a couple of somehow related use cases. Do this by creating different diagrams or using boundaries to split the sub-domains.

Avoid `<<include>>` and `<<extend>>`. Use cases undergo a synthesis an not an analysis. There are only very rare cases where one could use those relations in a useful way.

Answer (score 0):

> Can more use cases be added in this diagram?

This should not be your goal, therefore I daresay you don't want to ask this question. At least not anyone!

Instead, try to model the fewest possible UML entities without losing valuable information. Simplifying and splitting up diagrams into simpler parts is often way more challenging than modeling new entities.

The question is: Which information is required? You'll need to work that out with your stakeholders. Remember: [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).